# Weird vertical spacing with custom tcolorbox and tabular environment

Tags: tables, macros, vertical-alignment, tcolorbox

I'm trying to get the gray `codebox`'s to line up nicely with their explanations on the right side of the table, but clearly the vertical alignment is just a little off and I'm not sure why.

Additionally, if the explanation spans multiple lines, it seems like the problem is worse. Ideally, I'd like to have the `tcolorbox` on the left in the vertical middle of the explanation on the right.

**Bonus:** Is there something I can put in my `methodt` macro so I don't have to put `\code{}` around every entry on the left?

Here's an reproducible example, and below that is an image:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}  % Allows easy wrapping of text in tables
\usepackage{setspace}  % Allows setting line spacing throughout document
\usepackage{listings}  % Used for code sections
\usepackage{color}     % Used to define colors
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}  % Used to set page dimensions
\geometry{             % Setting margins
    top = 1in,
    bottom = 1in
}
\usepackage{hyperref}  % Allows blue styling of links and clickable table of contents
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor = blue
}

% Following allows inline code
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{dark-gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{.95}
%\newtcolorbox[〈init options〉]{〈name〉}[〈number〉][〈default〉]{〈options〉}

\newtcolorbox{codebox}{
    colback=light-gray,
    colframe=white
}
\newcommand{\code}[1] {
    \begin{codebox}
    {#1}
    \end{codebox}
}

\newtcolorbox{exbox} {
    colback=white,
    colframe=white
}
\newcommand{\ex}[1] {
    \begin{exbox}
        {#1}
    \end{exbox}
'}


%\renewcommand*\arraystretch{1.085}  % Setting vertical spacing in tables

\newcommand{\secspace}{\vspace{ .25in }}  % Separator between sections
\newcommand{\secline}{\vspace{ 6pt } \hrule width 2in \vspace{ 6pt }}  % Horizontal line between section title and content
\newenvironment{methodt}[1]  % Table for use with methods. Left side is method, right side is description
    {%
        \subsection{ #1 }
        \secline
        \begin{tabular}{ p{3.0in}p{2.5in} }
    }
    {%
        \end{tabular}
        \secspace
    }

% Defining colors for use in code segments
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{.95,.95,.95}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{.4,.4,.4}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.65, 0.12, 0.82}

% Defining the JavaScript language
\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
    keywords={typeof, new, true, false, catch, function, return, null, catch, switch, var, if, in, while, do, else, case, break},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    ndkeywords={class, export, boolean, throw, implements, import, this},
    ndkeywordstyle=\color{darkgray}\bfseries,
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    sensitive=false,
    comment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    commentstyle=\color{purple}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
    morestring=[b]',
    morestring=[b]"
}

% Setting properties of code blocks
\lstset{
    language=JavaScript,
    backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
    extendedchars=true,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showspaces=false,
    numbers=none,
    numberstyle=\footnotesize,
    numbersep=9pt,
    tabsize=2,
    breaklines=true,
    showtabs=false,
    captionpos=b
}

\begin{document}
    \setstretch{1.1}  % Set line spacing across document
    
    \begin{titlepage}
        \vspace*{\stretch{1.0}}
        \begin{center}
            \Large\textbf{Web Canvas API Reference --- Lite}\\
            \large\textbf{ Alex Eastman }
        \end{center}
        \vspace*{\stretch{2.0}}
    \end{titlepage}
    \clearpage
    
    \begin{flushleft}
        \tableofcontents
        \clearpage
        
        \section{Methods} \label{methods}
        
        % Rectangles
        \begin{methodt}{Rectangles}
            \code{rect(x, y, width, height)} & A rectangle whose top-left corner is at (x, y); Pen automatically moved\\
            \code{fillRect(x, y, width, height)} & A solid rectangle\\
            \code{strokeRect(x, y, width, height)} & An outline rectangle\\
            \code{clearRect(x, y, width, height)} & Clear a portion or all of a rectangle   
        \end{methodt}
    
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

[image: Image of Problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why these boxes are not aligning but I would do this differently and use a `sidebyside` [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox). If you define:

```
\newtcolorbox{CODE}{
    sidebyside,
    sidebyside align=top,
    colback=light-gray,
    colframe=white,
    bicolor,
    colbacklower=white,
    righthand width=2.5in
}
\newcommand\Code[2]{\begin{CODE}#1\tcblower#2\end{CODE}}
```

Then you can replace your method section with

```
    \begin{methodt}{Rectangles}
      \Code{rect(x, y, width, height)}{A rectangle whose top-left corner is at (x, y); Pen automatically moved}
      \Code{fillRect(x, y, width, height)}{A solid rectangle}
      \Code{strokeRect(x, y, width, height)}{An outline rectangle}
      \Code{clearRect(x, y, width, height)}{Clear a portion or all of a rectangle}
    \end{methodt}
```

(I have removed the `tabular` environment from the `methodt` environment) to produce:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}  % Allows easy wrapping of text in tables
\usepackage{setspace}  % Allows setting line spacing throughout document
\usepackage{listings}  % Used for code sections
\usepackage{color}     % Used to define colors
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}  % Used to set page dimensions
\geometry{             % Setting margins
    top = 1in,
    bottom = 1in
}
\usepackage{hyperref}  % Allows blue styling of links and clickable table of contents
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor = blue
}

% Following allows inline code
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\definecolor{dark-gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{.95}
%\newtcolorbox[〈init options〉]{〈name〉}[〈number〉][〈default〉]{〈options〉}

\newtcolorbox{CODE}{
    sidebyside,
    sidebyside align=top,
    colback=light-gray,
    colframe=white,
    bicolor,
    colbacklower=white,
    righthand width=2.5in
}
\newcommand\Code[2]{\begin{CODE}#1\tcblower#2\end{CODE}}

\newtcolorbox{exbox} {
    colback=white,
    colframe=white
}
\newcommand{\ex}[1] {%
    \begin{exbox}
        {#1}
    \end{exbox}%
'}


%\renewcommand*\arraystretch{1.085}  % Setting vertical spacing in tables

\newcommand{\secspace}{\vspace{ .25in }}  % Separator between sections
\newcommand{\secline}{\vspace{ 6pt } \hrule width 2in \vspace{ 6pt }}  % Horizontal line between section title and content
\newenvironment{methodt}[1]  % Table for use with methods. Left side is method, right side is description
    {%
        \subsection{ #1 }
        \secline
    }
    {%
        \secspace
    }

% Defining colors for use in code segments
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{.95,.95,.95}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{.4,.4,.4}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.65, 0.12, 0.82}

% Defining the JavaScript language
\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
    keywords={typeof, new, true, false, catch, function, return, null, catch, switch, var, if, in, while, do, else, case, break},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    ndkeywords={class, export, boolean, throw, implements, import, this},
    ndkeywordstyle=\color{darkgray}\bfseries,
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    sensitive=false,
    comment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    commentstyle=\color{purple}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
    morestring=[b]',
    morestring=[b]"
}

% Setting properties of code blocks
\lstset{
    language=JavaScript,
    backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
    extendedchars=true,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showspaces=false,
    numbers=none,
    numberstyle=\footnotesize,
    numbersep=9pt,
    tabsize=2,
    breaklines=true,
    showtabs=false,
    captionpos=b
}

\begin{document}
    \setstretch{1.1}  % Set line spacing across document

    \begin{titlepage}
        \vspace*{\stretch{1.0}}
        \begin{center}
            \Large\textbf{Web Canvas API Reference --- Lite}\\
            \large\textbf{ Alex Eastman }
        \end{center}
        \vspace*{\stretch{2.0}}
    \end{titlepage}
    \clearpage

    \begin{flushleft}
        \tableofcontents
        \clearpage

        \section{Methods} \label{methods}

        % Rectangles
        \begin{methodt}{Rectangles}
          \Code{rect(x, y, width, height)}{A rectangle whose top-left corner is at (x, y); Pen automatically moved}
          \Code{fillRect(x, y, width, height)}{A solid rectangle}
          \Code{strokeRect(x, y, width, height)}{An outline rectangle}
          \Code{clearRect(x, y, width, height)}{Clear a portion or all of a rectangle}
        \end{methodt}

\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Btw, I would also the [xcolor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) package package, instead of [color](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/color)...although I can not point to anywhere where this would make a difference:)

Comment: That’s a nice answer, thank you! Would ‘valign=center’ center the code on the left in the box?

Comment: @AlexEastman I am not sure if it possible to centre one side and the other. You want to use `sidebyside align` -- see page 120 of the manual. Try `sidebyside align=center seam`.

Comment: So I finally got around to trying this, and I'm getting an error that says "I do not know the key /tcb/bicolor", any idea why that would happen?

Comment: I had to add `\tcbuselibrary{skins}` and then it worked. Thanks!